# blender overwrote my animation after moving .blend file

Tags: animation

I am very new at blender and I have created an object (A tree like sprite) with 3 animations.

Those animations are spin, jump, and flip

All animations run from 80 frames (from 0 to 80)
All animations have different key frames.

As you can tell from their names they all do different things.

As I rendered and played my individual animations, they worked fine. 
Then I pressed the 'F' button to save those animations.

I don't know if this relates but I exported my project to a fbx file.

And finally, I moved the .blend and .blend1 files to somewhere else. 
Afterwards, I decided I wanted to move those files back.

After I moved the file back, I could no longer get all three animations. 
The animations turned out all to be the spin animation.

I couldn't find the error